# How to preserve formatting in a multiline <v-text-field>?

Tags: vuetify.js

I use `v-text-field` to gather a lengthy description from the user.

This description has line breaks but when looking at the Vue data element which holds the description I see that it is a string with just the content - the separators are gone.

**Is there a way to keep the new lines in the Vue data element?**

Comment: Can you provide CodePen or Fiddle exposing your issue ?

Comment: @Toodoo: I found the solution in the meantime, just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting is actually present, it is just not visible when analyzing the value (string) of the bound property.

An example of reuse of a `textarea` content is below. Type a few lines in the first `placeholder` and the content will be manipulated in several ways, with formatting preserved

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    comment: 'placeholder'
  },
  computed: {
    jcomment() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.comment)
    },
    bcomment() {
      return JSON.parse(this.jcomment)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>the textarea to type into</p>
  <v-text-field multi-line v-model="comment"></v-text-field>
  <p>a dynamic copy of the textarea above</p>
  <v-text-field multi-line v-model="comment"></v-text-field>
  <p>a "pre" version of the content</p>
  <pre>{{comment}}</pre>
  <p>a JSON version of the content</p>
  {{jcomment}}
  <p>the JSON version above, parsed and displayed in a textarea</p>
  <v-text-field multi-line v-model="bcomment"></v-text-field>
</div>
```

Comment: I am confused. Can't find "multi-line" attribute on https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props. What does it do?